# My PC is going to sleep immediately upon startup

Tags: windows-7, display, sleep

My computer is acting very strange lately.  Frequently, when I turn on my computer, the monitor immediately refuses to turn on - I just see the orange light and a message telling me the monitor is going into sleep mode.

Today, this happened with my entire computer, not just the monitor, I turned on my computer and it went straight to sleep.  When I woke it up from sleep mode, it went straight back to sleep.  Finally, on the second time around, it seems to have stayed active and I'm able to use my computer.

Anyone know what's going on?  It seemed to run fine when I booted in Safemode a few days ago, but not so much when I started it normally, which leads me to believe it's a driver issue, not a hardware problem, but this just started about a week ago and I can't think of any updates that would have caused this.

One more thing I should add: the one thing that I did change about a month or so ago was that I added a new hard drive to my computer.  Is it possible this is a defect in the new drive?  It's got a two year warranty, so I can send it back if it's likely this is the problem.

Comment: Check for virus.

Comment: Somehow I didn't even think about a virus.  Running a full system scan with Avast right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run a virus scan or 2. It looks to me like it could be a virus.

Comment: Looks like Avast found one.  I don't know why I didn't think of that earlier, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: If that solves your problem, I'd appreciate an acceptance. :)

Comment: I thought I'd give it a day or two to see if that solves the problem, and if it does, I'll come back and accept your answer.

Comment: Okay, computer's still working just fine, so I'll accept it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sharing from my experience. In my case, we tried anything possible until our last option was cleaning the motherboard since it was years since last cleaned, and voila! the problem was solved, i was really scared if the problem was the motherboard itself, but turns out not, i felt relieved, well when we cleaned we found out clumps of dirt around cpu fan, and it is really hot when touched, but oh well, if you pc is new then this would not be a solution for you.